# In iOS9.0, the MPVolumeSlider value is not holding proper value, It always 0.0

Tags: ios9, mpvolumeview

The following code works fine in iOS 8.0 devices, but in iOS9.0 always getting slider value as 0.000,

```
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    for subview in volumeView.subviews {
        if subview.isKindOfClass((NSClassFromString("MPVolumeSlider"))!) {
            let volumeSlider = subview as? UISlider
            print("volumeSlider value : \(volumeSlider?.value)")
        }
    }
```

console output :
volumeSlider value : Optional(0.0)

Any idea about this behaviour? I want to get master volume value. Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

After analysis i used **AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume** to get the master volume of iOS9.0 devices

Comment: The availability of `outputVolume` is >= iOS 6.0. Check documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/outputVolume). This is the documented way to get the system volume value in iOS.